# taking tables to be dumped as options in bash script to take dump of postgresql database

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, pg-dump

I want to take dump of specific tables of `postgresql` database. The command to take dump of specific tables is

```
pg_dump -h host -U username db_name -t table1 - t table2 -t table3 ... > /tmp/mydb.sql
```

But I am trying to take tables as an `option argument` while running bash script. The number tables to be dumped are not fixed. I am taking option argument as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
# Argument = -t test -r server -p password -v

usage()
{
cat << EOF
usage: $0 options

This script run the test1 or test2 over a machine.

OPTIONS:
   -h      Show this message
   -t      Table name
   -v      Verbose
EOF
}

TABLE=
VERBOSE=
while getopts “ht:v” OPTION
do
     case $OPTION in
         h)
             usage
             exit 1
             ;;
         t)
             TABLE=$OPTARG
             ;;
         v)
             VERBOSE=1
             ;;
         ?)
             usage
             exit
             ;;
     esac
done

if [[ -z $TABLE ]]
then
     usage
     exit 1
fi
```

How can I take multiple table name as argument in bash script to take the dump of those tables and embed in the `pg_dump` command?

Comment: I wouldn't use `-t` at all; just take the table names as positional parameters and pass them to `pg_dump` with `"$@"`.

Comment: @chepner Thankyou for the answer, can you please write the example. As I have seen that using `pg_dump` need `-t` option in front of each table name need to be dumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have any other non-optional arguments, let those be the tables.

```
tables=()
for table in "$@"; do
    tables+=(-t "$table")
done

pg_dump "${tables[@]}"
```

Comment: I tried this by running the following command `./myscript.sh table1 table2 table3`  and instead of using `"${tables[@]}"` in `pgdump`, I simply try to echo the values but it was blank.